# Flutter | Firebase User Authentication & Profile creation

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, firebase-authentication, backend

I am new to Flutter/Firebase and I want to program an app where a user can login/register and then he needs to create a profile with his information like his name, age... and only if he has created his profile, he should be able to continue and see the "main part" of the app.

I already implemented the Firebase Auth with a working Login / Register Page, but my question is now, how to create the Profile thing the most efficent.

At the moment I created this method here at my own:

```
  Future checkUserProfile() async{

// get snapshot from document
final snapShot = await Firestore.instance.collection('profiles').document(uid).get();

if(snapShot == null || !snapShot.exists){

  User.gotProfile = false;

} else {

  User.gotProfile = true;

}
```

This method is checking if an user-profile with the Firebase Auth User UID already exists and if not, the user will be send to the "ProfilePage" with a FutureBuilder executing the method above and if it already exists, he will see the main part of the app.

As I already said, I tried it by myself and I wanted to ask if this is already an good implementation or is there even an easier & better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is an good implementation. In my app I have the check User method like yours. The following method is an example. When the user is not registered he forwarded to the RegisterPage else he forwarded to the MainPage.

```
checkUserAlreadyExists(FirebaseUser user) async {
    final userData = await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).get();
    if (userData == null || !userData.exists) {
      setState(() {
        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => RegisterPage()), ModalRoute.withName('/'));
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MainPage()), ModalRoute.withName('/'));
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ahh okay, you did it already in the function. I created an extra widget for it, but it still should be the same. Thank you very much for sharing!

Comment: Yes exactly no problem you are welcome :) can you please accept the answer or can i help you with a other problem?